# How JQuery can parse colors in text?

Tags: jquery, css, colors

How to parse colors in text, if i type #40464f , i would like catch the color and apply it some CSS.

I know how to do that with added markup,

```
 <span data-color=""> #40464f </span>
```

for example.

But i would like to know if its possible to do that automatically without the needed to add markups manually ?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve so we can answer your question properly.

Comment: That is you have a text box, and want to apply the color to a div according to the input by the user in this text box???

Comment: What is this property data-color?

Comment: @ThiefMaster ; @jensgram understood my question, all i want is jQuery parse my text with is in a <div id="main"> and if it catch a color for example #ff0000 , jQuery will add some markup around it. i'm not good in english so its not simple to explain sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really knowing what's asked, I'll just provide a way to match (HEX) colors within an HTML element.

Given HTML:

```
<p id="subject">
    Here is a color: #fff. Red is #ff0000 while #9ab57d is another color.
</p>
```

Use JS:

```
$(function() {
    var m = $('#subject').text().match(/#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}/gi);
    // ['#fff', '#ff0000', '#9ab57d']

    $.each(m, function(i, v) {
        // `v` is each color...
    });
});
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/Z2Kfq/1/))

**Update**
[Demo where the colors are actually *used*](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/KCByP/1/):

HTML:

```
<p id="subject">
    Here is a color: #fff. Red is #ff0000 while #9ab57d is another color.
</p>
<ol id="result"></ol>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var m = $('#subject').text().match(/#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}/gi),
        $result = $('#result');

    $.each(m, function(i, v) {
        $('<li />').text(v).css('background-color', v).appendTo($result);
    });
});
```

**Update #2**
Based on comments, replacing inline ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/J5Pma/2/)):

HTML:

```
<p id="subject">
    Nous obtenons les 2 couleurs suivantes : #40464f &amp; #0f131a
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var $subject = $('#subject'),
        str = $subject.html();

    str = str.replace(/#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}/gim, "<span style=\"background-color: $&;\">$&</span>");
    $subject.html(str);
});
```

Comment: This is really useful, but how to add the markup directly around the parsed element ? not in the #result box please ?

for example ; i have this text : 

Nous obtenons les 2 couleurs suivantes : #40464f & #0f131a.

how can i obtain this :

Nous obtenons les 2 couleurs suivantes : <span style="background-color:#40464f">#40464f</span> &  <span style="background-color:#0f131a">#0f131a</span>.

i tried something like that with your method, but it doesn't work :

$(this).preprend("<span>").css('background-color', v);
$(this).append("</span>");

Comment: with this [amazing colors list](http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/ntc.js) how could be evolve your first demo to retriving hex and color name in <ol>

Answer (score 1):

Since I guess it's the text within the **span** you wish to check against I think that **regexp** matching is the way you have to go.

Here is a filter that allows regexp to be used for selecting elements.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

[Working Example on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ec8TH/)

```
<input /> <button>Change</button> <div></div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){

    $('div').css('background-color', $('input').val());  

  });

});
</script>
```

Or if it is the text color you wish to change just use `.css('color', $('input').val())`

Also, Note that your selectors should be better than mine!